# MVC SiteMapProvider not loading the nodes when hosted in IIS but works in VS Dev Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitemapprovider

I have added the MVC SiteMapProvider to the ASP.NET MVC4 App through nuget

Added the sitemap menu & sitemap path html helper in the layout.

When running the web application in Visual Studio Development Server i got the sitemap menu and sitemap path breadcrumb got generated successfully for the links i specified in the Mvc.Sitemap.

But when i try to run the same application in IIS Express or through IIS, Nodes are not getting generated. Just the `<ul class="menu"></ul>` generated without any nodes. No errors were thrown. In IIS i run as .net 4.0 integrated.

Any more configuration need to add or need to add any modules in order to run under IIS apart from the configuration generated from nuget in web.config.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Authorize attribute has been added in the global filters.
Made the security trimming to false in web.config.It worked out. Thanks.